# How can i upload files on Firebase storage inside folder with key generated names using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, firebase, firebase-storage

[image]

Here is an image of my Firebase storage which is used by Android and IOS i want save the same from the web also I am trying this it is storing data but not in the folder

```
var storesRef = rootRef.child('Audio');
storesRef.put(file, metadata);
```

Comment: Which folder are you referring to? Your files in screenshot are inside of "Audio" directory already (see the path at top).

Comment: yes this is of Audio path I want to upload in the same path I have also some other regarding files type I will manage according type of document

Comment: Can you please explain which path are you trying to upload file (try adding file directly in console to that path and share a screenshot)? What do you mean by `type of document` ? Are you trying to create sub-directory in Audio directory?

Comment: no, I want to upload in the Audio directory I have another directory too like I am uploading a PDF file then it goes on Document diractory

Comment: Okay, just to confirm do you need those random IDs? How are you generating those from Android then?

Comment: ye I need those id's too because the same chat is work for all Like Android,IOS and web too I don't have any idea how they are generating random Id's but here is the code which works for chat on my side
var storesRef = rootRef.child('chat').child(chat_user_ref).push();
      storesRef.set({
        chat_id:storesRef.getKey(),

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235089/discussion-between-rishikesh-singh-and-dharmaraj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Realtime database's push keys and get random IDs and use them as your file name in Firebase storage:

```
var filetype = "mp3"

var newPostKey = firebase.database().ref().child('temp').push().key;

var uploadTask = rootRef.child(`Audio/${newPostKey}.${filetype}`).put(file, metadata);
```